# MongoDB update query: field to be the sum of other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an inner array as the following:

```
[
    {'name': 'foo', 'size': 1},
    {'name': 'baz', 'size': 2},
    /* ... */

]
```

I'd like to update some outer field, `total` which is the sum of all sizes, without querying the array in advance.

I'm aware of the aggregate paradigm but I'm not sure how to apply it here, if needed at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline with `$out` to write to a new or existing collection

```
db.t61.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {total : {$sum : "$data.size"}}},
    {$out : "t61"}
])
```

sample collection and aggregation

```
> db.t61.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44d5709d56bf65be5ab2e2"), "data" : [ { "name" : "foo", "size" : 1 }, { "name" : "baz", "size" : 2 } ] }
> db.t61.aggregate([{$addFields : {total : {$sum : "$data.size"}}},{$out : "t61"}])
> db.t61.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c44d5709d56bf65be5ab2e2"), "data" : [ { "name" : "foo", "size" : 1 }, { "name" : "baz", "size" : 2 } ], "total" : 3 }
>
```